# How to use variable with or operator | in awk

Tags: awk

The following works:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR { sub(/\.(png|txt|jpg|json)$/,""); a[$0]; next }
            { f=$0; sub(/\.(png|txt|jpg|json)$/,"", f) }
    !(f in a)
' comp1.txt comp2.txt > result.txt
```

and now I want it to take the file endings that shall be ignored in the comparison as a variable, but cannot get it to work. My attempt below just compares without ignoring any file endings. I tried with $ and without, with () and without, escaping the |, but so far without success. What is the correct solution?

```
fileEndingsToIgnore="png|txt|jpg|json" 
awk -v fileEndingsToIgnore="${fileEndingsToIgnore}" '
    NR==FNR { sub(/\.(fileEndingsToIgnore)$/,""); a[$0]; next }
            { f=$0; sub(/\.(fileEndingsToIgnore)$/,"", f) }
    !(f in a)
' comp1.txt comp2.txt > result.txt
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One workaround is to dynamically build the regex and store it in a variable, then use the variable in the `sub()` call.

Sample input file:

```
$ cat test.file
abc.txt
def.jpg
ghi.exe
jkl.dat
123.json
456.ini
789.pngX
000.png
111.dat
```

One `awk` idea:

```
fileEndingsToIgnore="png|txt|jpg|json"

awk -v fileEndingsToIgnore="${fileEndingsToIgnore}" '
BEGIN { regex="\\.(" fileEndingsToIgnore ")$" }         # need to escape the escape char, ie, "\\"
      { out=$1
        sub(regex,"",out)
        printf "%s => %s\n",$0,out
      }
' test.file
```

This generates:

```
abc.txt => abc
def.jpg => def
ghi.exe => ghi.exe
jkl.dat => jkl.dat
123.json => 123
456.ini => 456.ini
789.pngX => 789.pngX
000.png => 000
111.dat => 111.dat
```

---

Applying this to OP's current code:

```
fileEndingsToIgnore="png|txt|jpg|json" 

awk -v fileEndingsToIgnore="${fileEndingsToIgnore}" '
    BEGIN   { regex="\\.(" fileEndingsToIgnore ")$" }
    NR==FNR { sub(regex,""); a[$0]; next }
            { f=$0; sub(regex,"", f) }
    !(f in a)
' comp1.txt comp2.txt > result.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I had no idea such a workaround was possible, this solves my problem.

Answer (score 2):

GNU `AWK` doesn't allow you to use variable *inside* regular expression literal, you might use string variable with `~` and `!~` and many [String functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html), however in such case you need to double escaping as explained in [Using Dynamic Regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Computed-Regexps.html). Consider following example, let say you want to output only `.txt` and `.json` filenames without extension and you have `file.txt` with content as follows

```
file1.txt
file2.bmp
file3.json
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{s="\\.(txt|json)$"}sub(s,""){print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
file1
file3
```

Observe `\\` rather than `\`.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Your example does not use any variables and neither does mine, but mine runs successfully with single escape. I just need it to use variables. So I don't understand how your example is relevant to my question, maybe you can clarify.

Comment: `s` in my example is variable of GNU `AWK`

Answer (score 0):

I think this should be generic enough :

> `"-v FS=..."` is the list of file extensions to exclude, case sensitive:

```
 mawk -v FS='mp[34]|txt|sh|awk' 'BEGIN { _^= FS = "[.]("FS")$" 

                split("",__) } FNR==NR ? __[$_] : NF<=($_ in __)' file file
```